# What should the Content-Type be for a 4xx error without a body?

Tags: http, http-headers, grape-api

Consider an HTTP request that gets the following response:

```
405 Method Not Allowed
Content-Length: 0
```

What should the content-type of something like this be?

- Set to nothing?
- Not set?
- Set to `text/plain` or `text/html`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should content-type header be present when the message body is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784398/should-content-type-header-be-present-when-the-message-body-is-empty)

Answer (score 23):

You haven't got any content, therefore I wouldn't set a `Content-Type` at all. If you find that causes problems to clients (which seems unlikely, to be honest), I'd probably go with `text/plain` - definitely not `text/html`, as your "empty content" is *not* an HTML document.

Comment: @dB.: It would have been useful to say so before. It sounds like you basically need to follow whatever the bug ends up deciding you need.