# Should Content-Type header be present when the message body is empty?

Tags: http, http-headers

Should the `Content-Type` header be present in an HTTP request or response when there is no payload body?

Is the correct combination of HTTP headers in this case to have no `Content-Type` and a `Content-Length` of 0, or should the `Content-Type` not be present at all when the message lacks a body?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should the Content-Type be for a 4xx error without a body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032932/what-should-the-content-type-be-for-a-4xx-error-without-a-body)

Comment: @RobinGreen: This question is more general and the answer quotes RFC, so it's better to keep this question and and close the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032932/what-should-the-content-type-be-for-a-4xx-error-without-a-body).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Content-Type should a 204 No Response use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029351/what-content-type-should-a-204-no-response-use)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) says:

> A sender that generates a message containing a payload body SHOULD
> generate a Content-Type header field in that message [...]

So it doesn't say explicitly what to do if you're generating a message that *doesn't* have a payload body, but it certainly seems implied that not sending a `Content-Type` header would be appropriate in that case.

`Content-Length: 0` is how you would indicate to the receiver that there will be no body, unless you're using something like chunked encoding.

Comment: Using RestEasy 3.15.4, I have the error `javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type` when doing a POST without body, with header `Content-Length: 0` and without `Content-Type` header. Adding `Content-Type: application/json` solved the problem. When the error occured, the server returns chunked response. That's strange because it was occuring only with my application, but when I did the same call with Postman, there was no error. Anyway, it's maybe safer to add a dummy content type because not all server-side implementation would understand that.

Comment: All "nothings" aren't equal. Take any typed language that supports the concept of null for example. A `Foo x = null` is not the same as `Bar y = null`. Similarly, an empty `application/json` response is not the same an empty `image/png` response. An empty JSON response would be interpreted as `null`, whereas an empty PNG is an error.