# Result From Integration Test Is Different In CI Build

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing, face-api

I have an integration test which creates an object and deletes it afterwards

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public async Task SetUp()
{
    var api = new Api();

    await api.Create("a");
}

[OneTimeTearDown]
public async Task CleanUp()
{
    var uri = "https://someuri/a";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Subscription-Key", "some_subscription_key");

    await client.DeleteAsync(uri);
}
```

Under one of my tests, the ContentType returned is null, however when this same test gets run on my continuous integration build it returns "application/json".

```
[Test]
public void Train_WhenCalled_ContentTypeShouldBeNull()
{
    var result = _api.Train("a")
        .Result
        .Content
        .Headers
        .ContentType;

    Assert.That(result, Is.Null);
}

// Train Method
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Train(string id)
{
    string uri = $"https://someuri/{ id }/train";

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Subscription-Key", "some_subscription_key");

    return await client.PostAsync(uri, null);
}
```

The documentation of this API states that indeed it should return an empty json so I am confused as to why in my local machine it returns null. Running vstest.console.exe manually marks all my integration tests as passed. Please help!

Comment: Are you *sure* the docs say an actual empty JSON response will be returned instead of eg a 201-Created *without* a body? Or a 202 or 204?

Comment: .NET's HttpClient doesn't have a GetHttpClient() method. I suspect it's a hand-made factory method (why not use HttpClientFactory?) used to mock HttpClient (the proper way is to pass a moch handler to HttpClient's constructor). It's not possible to say what's wrong without knowing what GetHttpClient() does. Which API are you trying to call?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, the response code is 202 with an empty JSON body. Refer to this link: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395249

I modified the code. The GetHttpClient() method is a helper method that I created myself.

Comment: Once you get a 202 you don't care about the rest of the data. An empty body doesn't need a content type. A content type is only required when there *is* a payload. Check this [probably duplicate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784398/should-content-type-header-be-present-when-the-message-body-is-empty). An empty body should have a `Content-Length` header of 0.

Comment: Why do you care about the empty payload's content type though? That's unit testing Azure's API. It could easily be that you are connecting to different environments (staging vs production) or different service versions with insignificant differences.

Comment: You do have a point. The only reason why I decided to test the content type is because of an article I read which states that when doing an integration test on a RESTful API you only need to assert three things: status code, content type, and the actual content.

Comment: Now my other integration test related to the Train method had an error as well. Instead of returning status code of accepted it returned conflict. Could it be that this is because CI builds are run concurrently in VSTS?